# How to replace SiteContextSlot content?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I would like to replace the language and currency selector from spartacus to one of my own and add some more content. The problem is I can't cxOutletRef the SiteContextSlot. I can't override the LanguageComponent and CurrencyComponet, and if I could, I wouldn't want to have Language - Currency but Currency - Language. So what I really need to know is how can I change the SiteContextSlot.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SiteContext` slot (not 'SiteContextSlot' btw) is defined in the CMS, and it contains 2 components by default. Both are of type `CMSSiteContextComponent`. The `CMSSiteContextComponent` has a property ('context') to define the actual context.

The context is picked up by the `SiteContextSelectorComponent` which delegates the logic to `SiteContextComponentService`. The `SiteContextComponentService` uses a generic approach to load a list of context in a select element.

If you want to change the order or context selectors in the `SiteContext`, I recommend the following:

- Changing the order simply by changing the order of the components inside the `SiteContextSlot` in the CMS
- Drop a context; simply remove a component from `SiteContextSlot`
- Add a custom context (component).

There are different options to add a new context:
- Add a new instance of the `SiteContextSelectorComponent`. This is fairly complex, as you need to introduce a new context in the backend (just an enum though) and extend the `SiteContextComponentService` so that the new context can be used.
- Create your own context component to render additional context
- Create your custom component to render all context (you'd replace all components inside `SiteContextSlot` and add your new component).
- Forget about CMS at all, and as you suggested override the slot all together. This works fine with outlets actually.

You can also mix and match the above options:

- keep existing components in CMS (but probably reorder them)
- use an outlet with `OutletPosition` where you'd have additional components.

The below code shows you this in code

```html
<ng-template cxOutletRef="SiteContext" cxOutletPos="after">
  more context
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Good to hear, what solution did you end up using? 
And can you "accept" the answer to mark this one as done?

Comment: I ended up overriding the SiteContextSelectorComponent, because I wanted to change the way it was displaying the selector, then I made a new component (CurrencyLanguageUIComponent) where I'm using my new SiteContextSelector. This way I could change the order (language/currency to currency/language). Finally, in app.component.html, `<ng-template cxOutletRef="SiteContext">
  <app-language-currency-ui></app-language-currency-ui>
</ng-template>`.

Comment: sounds good. Instead of using the outlets,  you might want to consider component mapping instead. That's a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite this CMS component using `cmsComponents` config of Spartacus. See docs https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/#page-title

The component name to use in the cms mapping config is `LanguageCurrencyComponent` (or `CMSSiteContextComponent` depending on your actual CMS data).

Comment: Thanks @Platonn but none of that works. If I use CMSSiteContextComponent in cms config it will duplicate what im trying to show rather then delete the Language and Currency selectors, because the CMSSiteContextComponent has 2 components inside. Also, if I try to overwrite LanguageCurrencyComponent it wont change anything.

Comment: I would need to dig more why mapping `CMSSiteContextComponent` causes duplication. I hope you can take a look at the source code of the original implementation of this component and deduce how to avoid a duplicated render. Here is the original module https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/storefrontlib/src/cms-components/misc/site-context-selector/site-context-selector.module.ts#L21-L30

Comment: Thanks @Platonn but the reason why it duplicates it's very clear. Inside the SiteContextSlot exists 2 CMSSiteContextComponent (Language and Currency). If I overwrite the CMSSiteContextComponent it will change both. Other example of this case is the CMSLinkComponent. If I would want to change what is inside of the SiteLinksSlot (Find Store, Help, Contact Us), I can't overwrite the CMSLinkComponent, because what ever HTML I produce it will be shown 3 times (it will replace the Find Store, Help, Contact Us).